# Proporciones slider (jquery.slider.)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slider

Tengo un problema realizando un slider con jquery.slider.js
El slider me funciona correctamente el problema es la proporción de la imagen. Tiene como una proporción establecida y para ajustar el tamaño solo me deja cambiar el width. En función de este, se adapta el height mostrado y todo lo que sobresale, lo corta. El height da igual el valor que ponga, porque lo ignora. Tengo una imagen que es muy “alta” en comparación con el ancho, y por ello la única forma que tengo de que se vea entera es colocar el width muy grande, pero entonces me aparece un barra de scroll horizontal. Si pongo el width al 100% o aproximadamente al tamaño de la pantalla, la imagen se me corta por la mitad.
¿Hay alguna forma de ajustar el width y el height independientemente?

Muchas Gracias de antemano.

El código es algo así:

Html----------------

```
<section id="container">
         <div class="slides">
               <div id="slide1">
                    ……
               </div>
               <div id="slide2">
                    ……
               </div>
         </div>
</section>
```

CSS-----------------

```
#container{
      width:900px
     height:2300px;
}
```

Comment: De que hay una forma la hay, pero la verdad es que sin el código del plugin y la imagen en concreto es muy difícil saber, ¿Tienes forma de subir tu proyecto a un servidor y publicarlo? si es **no** trata de subirlo a **jsfiddle** o **codepen**, la imagen la puedes subir a **imgur**. Así será más facil darte una respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

La idea es muy simple con CSS y HTML, en tu caso ya tienes la estructura y le has dado un `width:900px` al `<section id="container">` este es tu contenedor principal.

Fijate en el código fuente del ejemplo con ctrl+u o inspeccionar sobre una imágen: [Ejemplo de slider.js](http://www.slidesjs.com/examples/standard/).

Una vez que ya tienes el contenedor con un tamaño fijo seteado (Como en tu caso) solo te queda añadir a las etiquetas `<img ../>` un tamaño dinámico que se adapte al tamaño de tu contenedor (el de 900px).

Ejemplo:

```
<div id="slides">
  <div class="slidesjs-container" style="width: 900px; height: 2300px;">
    <div class="slidesjs-control">
      <img src="1.jpg" class="slidesjs-slide" slidesjs-index="0" style="width: 100%;">
      <img src="2.jpg" class="slidesjs-slide" slidesjs-index="1" style="width: 100%">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="slidesjs-previous slidesjs-navigation"> < </a>
  <a href="#" class="slidesjs-next slidesjs-navigation"> > </a>
</div>
```

Espero que te ayude.

Un Saludo.

Comment: Hola UHDante. No funcionó el código pero chequeé el link  que pusiste "Ejemplo de slider.js." y pude ver que dentro del sript puedo declarar las dimensiones del slider: 
   <script> 
   $(function(){
    $(".slides").slidesjs({
    width: 900,
    height: 2300,
    });
   });
  </script>
y esto me función. Gracias por el link.